# How do I aggregate on all columns in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have simple table:

```
j:([] x: til 10; y: til 10; g: 10#`a`b`c)

x y g
-----
0 0 a
1 1 b
2 2 c
3 3 a
4 4 b
5 5 c
6 6 a
7 7 b
8 8 c
9 9 a
```

How can I aggregate by `g` without explicitly specifying each column:

e.g. good, but not working:

`select sum by g from j`

vs bad, but works:

`select sum x, sum y by g from j`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would

```
   sum''[`g xgroup j]
```

Work?

Comment: This is the right answer, exactly what `xgroup` is designed for: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xgroup. I'm not sure the answer about using a functional select as it's more performant is accurate, at least not on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional select which will give better performance as well.

```
?[j;();enlist[`g]!(),`g;raze  {enlist[x]!enlist (sum;x)} each cols[j] except `g]
```

Comment: `The q interpreter parses delete, exec, select, and update into their equivalent functional forms, so there is no performance difference.`

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

Comment: I am comparing it to 'xgroup' query from another answer and not with a normal select statement( which I know will be the same as functional select).

Comment: ```q
?[j; (); g!g; .[!]1((sum;)')\(cols j)except g:1#`g]
```

Comment: Just a refactoring to remove the `enlist`s: `(sum;)'` <=> `enlist[sum;] each`, while the Zen monks ``1 f\`` form gives the L and R args of Dict as respectively `\`x\`y` and `(sum;) each \`x\`y`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this frequently you may want to create a simple function `fnby` (not to be confused with `fby`!) which is nothing more than a functional form equivalent of `select fn[col1],fn[col2],..,fn[colN] by b from t`:

```
fnfnby:{[t;fn;b]?[t;();b!b,:();c!(fn;)each c:cols[t]except b]}
```

and then use it however you need:

```
fnby[j;sum;`g]
/or
fnby[j;any 7<;`g]
/etc.
```