# How do I apply function to all columns in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a table of minute return data.

To squash it to daily data, I'm currently doing:

```
select sum XLK, sum XLE, sum XLY, sum BTAL, sum BND, sum GLD, sum UVXY, sum SPY by t.date from r
```

Is there a way I can not repeat the `sum`?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088427/how-do-i-aggregate-on-all-columns-in-kdb/74117332#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid repeating `sum` by using functional form. First step is to parse the statement to create a parse tree, which gives the form your expression needs to take.

```
q)parse"select sum XLK, sum XLE, sum XLY, sum BTAL, sum BND, sum GLD, sum UVXY, sum SPY by t.date from r"
?
`r
()
(,`date)!,`t.date
`XLK`XLE`XLY`BTAL`BND`GLD`UVXY`SPY!((sum;`XLK);(sum;`XLE);(sum;`XLY);(sum;`BTAL);(sum;`BND);(sum;`GLD);(sum;`UVXY);(sum;`SPY))
```

That information can then be used to create the equivalent functional form.

```
?[r;();enlist[`date]!enlist`t.date;{x!sum,/:x}`XLK`XLE`XLY`BTAL`BND`GLD`UVXY`SPY]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can pay to switch from SQL to vectors. Key moves below are use of `xgroup` and `sum''`.

```
c:cols[r]except`t  /in this case
tmp:0!`d xgroup update d:t.date from r
flip(`d,c)!flip tmp[`d],'(sum'')tmp[;c]
```

(Wrap in a lambda so `tmp` disappears.)

Illustration:

```
q)//table of random ints
q)c:`XLK`XLE`XLY`BTAL`BND`GLD`UVXY`SPY
q)show r:flip (`t,c)!enlist[(20?.z.d-til 5)+20?12:00],8 20#160?1000
t                             XLK XLE XLY BTAL BND GLD UVXY SPY
---------------------------------------------------------------
2023.03.13D04:55:00.000000000 109 251 212 848  255 675 694  299
2023.03.13D01:18:00.000000000 367 71  207 832  228 841 459  660
2023.03.13D08:59:00.000000000 877 780 284 117  246 674 400  38
2023.03.14D05:31:00.000000000 903 482 537 914  431 66  122  351
2023.03.15D04:38:00.000000000 231 547 650 470  748 656 639  997
2023.03.13D03:48:00.000000000 772 77  977 446  372 656 394  525
2023.03.14D01:12:00.000000000 427 238 868 755  853 703 997  88
2023.03.11D11:51:00.000000000 169 153 18  200  636 295 292  867
..
q)show delete t from tmp:0!`d xgroup update d:t.date from r
d          XLK                        XLE                         XLY        ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
2023.03.13 109 367 877 772 15 335 950 251 71 780 77 897 277 583   212 207 284..
2023.03.14 903 427 428 394 390 36 795 482 238 586 522 261 305 546 537 868 365..
2023.03.15 ,231                       ,547                        ,650       ..
2023.03.11 169 958 939 738 662        153 641 846 805 473         18 951 844 ..

q)flip(`d,c)!flip tmp[`d],'(sum'')tmp[;c]
d          XLK  XLE  XLY  BTAL BND  GLD  UVXY SPY
--------------------------------------------------
2023.03.13 3425 2936 2214 3710 2729 4714 3984 3421
2023.03.14 3373 2940 4231 4784 4510 2839 3504 2533
2023.03.15 231  547  650  470  748  656  639  997
2023.03.11 3466 2918 2657 2941 3154 2329 3109 2621
```